# Position of child of instance variable not updating

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

Hopefully this is a fairly simple question. I create an instance variable named `tutorialBox1` from my main game scene `Grid.m`. Inside my class `TutorialBox.m`, I create a sprite named `textBox1`, and as I tap on the main game scene, I want the position of that sprite, `textBox1` to be updated. I've been trying to figure out for hours why the position of the sprite will not update after adding the child once. Here is my attempt, and all the necessary code.

**Grid.m**

```
@ implementation Grid {
    TutorialBox *tutorialBox1;
}

-(void)checkTutorials {
    //This method is called upon loading of the scene
    tutorialBox1 = (TutorialBox*)[CCBReader load:@"TutorialBox"] //creates instance of variable using Spritebuilder (don't worry if you don't use SB, this part works)
    [tutorialBox1 updateBoxDisplay:1] //used to add text box child to textBox1
    [self addChild:tutorialBox1];
}

-(void)gridTapped {
    //When game scene is tapped, this is called to update position of textBox1 in tutorialBox1
    [tutorialBox1 updateBoxDisplay:2]; //updates position of textBox1 in tutorialBox1
}
```

**TutorialBox.m**

```
@ implementation Grid {
    CCSprite9Slice *textBox1;
}

-(void)didLoadFromCCB {
    //Called upon initialization of tutorialBox1
    textBox1 = [CCSprite9Slice spriteWithImageNamed:@"RetroSprites/tutorialtextBox1.png"];
}

-(void)updateBoxDisplay:(int)newTutorialLevelNumber {
    if (newTutorialLevelNumber == 1) {
        textBox1.position = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:textBox1];
    }
    else if (newTutorialLevelNumber == 2) {
        textBox1.position = ccp(100,100)
    }
}
```

**TutorialBox.h**

```
@interface TutorialBox : CCNode

- (void)updateBoxDisplay:(int)newTutorialLevelNumber

@end
```

I have checked to make sure everything is running properly with print statements, so it isn't an issue with anything else. It is simply being called, but the position in my main game scene, `Grid.m` is not being updated.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about this, but I guess its issue with the threading. Give a try with this code:

```
-(void)updateBoxDisplay:(int)newTutorialLevelNumber {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       if (newTutorialLevelNumber == 1) {
          textBox1.position = ccp(0,0);
          [self addChild:textBox1];
       }
       else if (newTutorialLevelNumber == 2) {
          textBox1.position = ccp(100,100)
       }

   });
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I'm a bit confused why this is a threading issue though, so lemme know if you have any more comments on that. I feel like when I run into threading issues it often has to do with calls that take place right after one another, and the order of completion matters. This doesn't seem to be the case here though, since it still doesn't work if I wait a long time in between loading the scene and my first tap on the scene

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `updateBoxDisplay` method, and then check on threading call stack window, you will find that this method call will be on secondary threads, rather being on Main Thread (first thread). To check thread stack, press **CMD + 6**.